# Java - How to disable SSL Certification Validation

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a request using a custom Axis2 soap library.

**The target URL that I am testing does not have a valid certification** so I need a way to accept all incomming requests.

I tried stuff like `X509TrustManager` but doesn't work.

The problem is that I'm getting

> Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path
>   building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

Any ideas?

Comment: "I tried stuff like X509TrustManager but doesn't work." - Show what you did.

Comment: please show the code you have used and the exact error message;  see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).